# Group events based on their dates then their dates and display them in my partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

[image]

I have a model with the list of events that includes start date, end date, start time, end time, title, and description. I need them to be grouped based on the Start date, then grouped based on the start hour and displayed in my partial view, like the attached image.

Here's my model:

```
public int eventID { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Title")]
public string eventTitle { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Description")]
public string PaperDescription { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Location")]
public string ClassLocation { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
```

Here's my controller:

```
public PartialViewResult _Events(DateTime? date)
        {
            var eventList = db.Classes_tbl.Where(x => x.StartDate == date).OrderBy(x => x.StartDate).ToList();            
            return PartialView(eventList);
        }
```

and here's my partial:

```
@foreach (var eventClass in Model.classesViewModel)
{

    if (eventClass.classType == ClassType.Event)
    {

    @eventClass.StartTime.GetValueOrDefault().Hours<br />
    @eventClass.EndTime<br />
    @eventClass.ClassTitle<br />
    }
}
```

Can someone help me please? I am very new to MVC and can't figure out how to do that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Create new ViewModel `EventGroup`
then select your events and group them by startdate then pass this view model to your view

```
var eventList = events
    .GroupBy(x => x.StartDate).Select(g => new EventGroup
    {
        StartDate = g.Key,
        Events = g.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).ToList()
    }).ToList();

public class EventGroup
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
public class Event
{
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    public string eventTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string PaperDescription { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Location")]
    public string ClassLocation { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan? StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan? EndTime { get; set; }
}

<div>
@foreach (var EventGroup in Model.EventGroups)
{
    @EventGroup.StartDate
    @foreach (var Event in EventGroup.Events)
    {
        if (Event.classType == Event.Event)
        {
        @Event.StartTime.GetValueOrDefault().Hours<br />
        @Event.EndTime<br />
        @Event.ClassTitle<br />
        } 
    }    
}         
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. It's still displaying each event and its date on my view. How do I display each group of events with the same date (4/23/2019) in one div and the date will display on top of the div, like the image attached. So each <div> will only hold the events happening in the same day.

Comment: I keep getting a null exception for @EventGroup.StartDate